# Python / PyQT input field crashes during autocomplete unless a value is selected first

Tags: python, autocomplete, pyqt

My program pulls data from a hard-coded dictionary and also adds some from a .csv so when I select a last name in my lineEdit, two other input fields populate with an associated e-mail address and phone number.

When I click into my lineEdit and begin typing a name, the autocomplete feature doesn't activate. If I press enter after typing in a name that exists in my dictionary, my entire program crashes. However, if I first select the dropdown and pick any random name, it seems to activate my autocomplete and I can type in any other name, find it, and press enter to populate other fields.

dictionary:

```
autocompleteList2 = {
' ': [' ', ' '],
'Adams': ['Adams@gmail.com', '555-555-5555'],
```

How I manipulated my other inputs:

```
class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):        
    def __init__(self, cList):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)                                 

        self.cList = cList
        self.Input_7.addItems(sorted(cList.keys())) 
        self.Input_7.activated[str].connect(self.onActivatedText)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def onActivatedText(self, text):
        self.Input_8.setText(self.cList[text][0])
        self.Input_9.setText(self.cList[text][1])
```

Dictionary linked:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app  = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window(autocompleteList2)
    w.show()
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    palette = QtGui.QPalette()
```

How can I get auto complete to activate as soon as I click into Input_7 (a lineEdit)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by deleting the spaces:

```
autocompleteList2 = {
'': ['', '', ''],
}
```

It was crashing because I'd try entering data that wasn't there (space before name).